# Use word document as template and replace tags inside

Tags: php

I've looked everywhere but have found nothing, I've got a word document importer on my website  and my client would like to import a word document with tags like %Test1 and these would be replaced by a PHP script and exported in a .doc format.

I've no idea how to go about doing this, so pointers or examples would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a great library to do just this: PHPWord.